# ffmpeg framemd5 - how do you get the checksums to match between LPCM and FLAC?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, checksum, flac

I'm converting losslessly compressed video and audio files (Utvideo/LCPM) into the FFV1/FLAC codecs using MKV as a container to save on storage space without compromise in quality. I'm using ffmpeg's framemd5 features to ensure that each conversion is 1:1 with the original capture in terms of output.

The batch script is as follows:

`for %%a in ("*.avi") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -f framemd5 "%%~na.framemd5"`

However, when using FLAC as the audio codec, the audio portion of the framemd5 outputs no longer match.

Here are the first 1001 lines of the framemd5 of a sample recording:

https://pastebin.com/axcf3f0a original LPCM

https://pastebin.com/3n75YTMj FLAC conversion

The problem seems to be that [FLAC adds additional metadata and its own checksum](http://dericed.com/papers/reconsidering-the-checksum-for-audiovisual-preservation/), so that while the audio is supposedly 1:1, framemd5 doesn't recognize it as such. I'm not well versed in the file structure of FLAC so I can't really verify that for myself or come up with a workaround.

Is there anyway to reconcile this? Can I create framemd5 files that checksum both video and audio between both Utvideo/LPCM and FFV1/FLAC as 1:1?

This is incredibly frustrating. I want to use FLAC to compress the audio since I'm already trying to save as much space as possible.

Comment: While I've given solutions to this in my answer, IMHO it's much easier to simply use something like `-f s16le -` and pipe the output to an external `md5sum` program to hash the stream as a whole (although relatively speaking such program is less "accessible" in Windows than in Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the metadata of the FLAC stream.

[`ffmpeg-all` on framehash](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#framehash) (framemd5 is a variant of framehash):

> By default audio frames are converted to signed 16-bit raw audio and video frames to raw video before computing the hash

(NOTE: in the case of higher bit depth, you will need to specify the corresponding *encoder*, for example `-c:a pcm_s24le` *after* `-f framemd5` in both the "A and B" cases to avoid checksum being performed on "truncated" audio frames.)

So the checksum is always performed on decoded (and then encoded, in a somewhat "bogus" way like the PCM cases or not) frames unless you specified something like `-c copy`. Therefore, the metadata would not "interfere" with the hashing here.

The real cause of the problem here is that unlike the case of a video, the "frame" in the case here when applied to the audio stream does not refer to a single sample, but samples as a whole that were grouped into a packet. The packets can have different sizes (number of samples) depending on the encoder / muxer (defaults in their code), and perhaps, setting from the user.

As you can see from the output lines, each packet in the input audio stream has 1024 samples in the case of PCM, whereas in the FLAC case, each has 4608 samples.

TL;DR. The solution here would be to add `-frame_size 1024` after `-c:a flac` when you encode the "compressed version".

P.S. I have no idea whether in any case changing the frame/packet size of the FLAC stream would cause you any problem (e.g. in playback) / undesirable side effect though, and you may wonder whether or not you can change frame/packet size of the PCM stream instead. All I can tell is that in the case of PCM, it would be a muxer level thing instead of a encoder level of thing like the case of FLAC, <s>which more or less implies that it is unlikely to be user-configurable</s>.

While it might or might not help, you can always try to mux (from raw stream files, or WAVE/AIFF files if it's PCM, instead of remuxing a Matroska file, since the process involved can be / are different) it with another Matroska muxer in case the PCM-in-Matroksa packet/frame size (i.e. `1024`) in ffmpeg does not work well when used for FLAC.

UPDATE: Apparently if you use WAVE file as input, you can use the `-max_size` *demuxer* option (of the WAVE dexmuer) to determine how big each packet is when the stream is fed into the Matrokska muxer. Note that `-max_size` is in bytes instead of samples though. So in this case you can use something like `ffmpeg ... -max_size 9216 -i path/to/input.wav ...` (make sure the you have `-max_size` *before* `-i`). I don't seem to see similar option available in the raw PCM demuxers (e.g. `s16le`), so you'll need to make the input audio file a WAVE file first if you need to use this instead.

Ref. (location in code of the defaults):
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.1.2/libavcodec/flacenc.c#L314
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.1.2/libavformat/pcm.c#L27
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.1.2/libavformat/wavdec.c#L76

Comment: Using `-frame_size 1024` after `-c:a flac` seems to make the hash values 1:1, and the videos seem to play normally, *but* the [DTS (decoding time stamp) and PTS (presentation time stamp)](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html) have shifted. Is this bad? The DTS and PTS seem to match each other on each line, but I want to make sure it's not a problem before continuing. I'm not familiar with this concept so it kind of freaks me out. 

https://pastebin.com/cdM0W4Uy - original LPCM

https://pastebin.com/xH5axNY5 - FLAC conversion, using `-frame_size 1024` after `-c:a flac`

Comment: @AntonioBanderéz Unfortunately I don't know much about timestamping (or block/frame size requirements in FLAC). All I can suggest is to use the `-max_size` alternative to change the frame size of the uncompressed/PCM version instead.